# Something different between array and generics

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I just read 《Effective Java》and I saw a sentence which said that

**As a consequence, arrays provide runtime type safety but not compile-time type safety and vice versa for generics**

I don't quite clear about it and I'm confused even after I've read all the examples given.Can anyone explain this to me,thanks a million.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't change the type of an array (reference) at runtime. But you can compile code which *tries* to just fine.

```
String[] strings = new String[1];
Object[] objects = strings;
objects[0] = new Integer(1); // RUN-TIME FAILURE
```

When you *compile* your application, no error will be thrown by the compiler.

On the other hand, if you use generics, this WILL give you an error when you compile (build) your application.

```
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
a.add(5); //Adding an integer to a String ArrayList - compile-time failure
```

In other words, you don't need to actually run your application and execute that section of code to find the problem.

**Note, compile time failures are preferable to run time failures, since you find out about the problem before you release it to users (after which it's too late)!**

Answer (score 0):

With generic collections, this code, which tries to put an Integer into a String list, gives a compile time error on the second line: `Cannot cast from List<String> to List<Object>`:

```
List<String> listOfStrings = new ArrayList<>();
List<Object> listAgain = (List<Object>)listOfStrings;
listAgain.add(123);
```

The equivalent code with arrays compiles perfectly because it is legal to use a String array as an Object array. (Technically speaking, arrays are [covariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29#Covariant_arrays_in_Java_and_C.23).)

```
String[] arrayOfStrings = new String[10];
Object[] arrayAgain = arrayOfStrings;
arrayAgain[0] = 123;
```

However, it wouldn't be a valid String array if it actually contained integers, so every operation to store something in it is checked at run time. At run time does it blow up with an `ArrayStoreException`.

Comment: Thank you very much,also a excellent example which helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Java Array provides covariant return type while generic doesn't provide covariant return type.

 
Lets understand with simple example

```
public class GenericArrayDiff {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Vehicle> vehicleList = null;
        List<Car> carList =  null;
        Vehicle[] vehicleArrays;
        Car[] carArrays;

        // illegal
        carList = vehicleList;
        // illegal
        vehicleList = carList;
        // illegal
        carArrays = vehicleArrays;
        // legal because array provides covariant return type
        vehicleArrays = carArrays;
    }

}
class Vehicle {

}
class Car extends Vehicle {

}
```